# Scala reflection: can I see if something is a (case) object?

Tags: scala, reflection

Is there a way in Scala to see if a class was defined as an object?

```
def isObject(c: Class[_]): Boolean = ???

object X
class Y

val x = X
val y = new Y

isObject(x.getClass) == true
isObject(y.getClass) == false
```

Comment: Why is this important for you? What difference is for you between `val obj = new Y` or `val obj = new AnyRef { }` or `object obj {}`?

Comment: It's not important, just curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `scala-reflect`, following seems to work:

```
object ObjectReflection extends App {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def isObject[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Boolean = PartialFunction.cond(tag.tpe) {
    case SingleType(_, _) => true
  }

  object AnObject
  case object ACaseObject
  class AClass
  case class ACaseClass(i: Int)
  trait ATrait

  println("new AClass     " +  isObject(new AClass))
  println("ACaseClass(42) " +  isObject(ACaseClass(42)))
  println("new ATrait {}  " +  isObject(new ATrait {}))
  println("AnObject       " +  isObject(AnObject))
  println("ACaseObject    " +  isObject(ACaseObject))

}
```

Prints:

```
new AClass     false
ACaseClass(42) false
new ATrait {}  false
AnObject       true
ACaseObject    true
```

Depends on:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

Comment: I hardcoded scala version into the dependency, which is quite wrong. Thanks @Suma for the edit ! Also edited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326545/get-fully-qualified-method-name-in-scala-macros/53375332#53375332 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391593/reflect-toolbox-worked-in-scala-2-11-not-working-in-scala-2-12/53392291#53392291

Answer (score 2):

As a first approximation, you can do

```
def isObject(c: Class[_]): Boolean = c.getName.endsWith("$")
```

because the anonymous class created for a singleton `object y` has name `y$`, and the usual anonymous classes (such as `new AnyRef {}`) end in `$<number>` instead.

But it's legal to create `class y$` as well, which would give a false positive; such names are rare in practice, though.

Using [scala-reflect](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/environment-universes-mirrors.html) should allow a more precise answer.